# How can I add new commited files to an existing branch in git

Tags: git, github

How can I add new committed files to an existing branch in git

I have created a branch after that I had added & Committed new files. Now I want to add those files to the existing branch

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge

Comment: So, the branch you committed on and existing branch are different?

Answer (score 1):

To choose a commit from one branch and apply it onto another, you may use `git cherry-pick <commit-id>`. An example from [Ariejan Blog](https://www.devroom.io/2010/06/10/cherry-picking-specific-commits-from-another-branch/):

```
dd2e86 - 946992 - 9143a9 - a6fd86 - 5a6057 [master]
           \
            76cada - 62ecb3 - b886a0 [feature]
```

Let’s say you’ve written some code in commit `62ecb3` of the feature branch that is very important right now. It may contain a bug fix or code that other people need to have access to now. Whatever the reason, you want to have commit `62ecb3` in the master branch right now, but not the other code you’ve written in the feature branch.

Here comes git cherry-pick. In this case, `62ecb3` is the cherry and you want to pick it!

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick 62ecb3
```

That’s all. `62ecb3` is now applied to the master branch and commited (as a new commit) in master. cherry-pick behaves just like merge. If git can’t apply the changes (e.g. you get merge conflicts), git leaves you to resolve the conflicts manually and make the commit yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what your question might be. You are having **master**, **testing**, **development** branches.

Your working on **master** branch and might have added **file1.txt** and **file2.txt** and you staged and committed them.

Now you realised that you should have done that work and commit in **development** branch.

So to simply fix this you can checkout to master branch and do the **soft** reset till the files you had worked.

**For eg** : The following is your git log details

```
wifi@wifi:/var/www/html/git_training$ git log
commit 11360c3a40697273c7a6bb742c47b00df928befa
Author: Channaveer Hakari <channaveer@wifidabba.com>
Date:   Sun Dec 3 13:11:41 2017 +0530

    Added test file

commit 0f3fed0b43c09b5fc3eee77dac4028bf0779e510
Merge: 825dd38 95f62fb
Author: Channaveer Hakari <channaveer@wifidabba.com>
Date:   Fri Dec 1 13:23:09 2017 +0530

    Merge branch 'issue1'
```

**Added test file** with hash value **11360c3a4069727...** is the commit that you want to soft reset then you need to go one level back to that commit ie to commit **Merge branch 'issue1'** with hash value **0f3fed0b43c09b5fc3eee77**.

```
wifi@wifi:/var/www/html/git_training$ git reset --soft 0f3fed0b43c09
```

Once you do **soft** reset the files till the commit you have done will get uncomitted and will show in the **staged** level as shown in the following way.

```
wifi@wifi:/var/www/html/git_training$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   test.txt
```

Now you can **reset** the master branch to make the file sit to your **local** as shown in the following

```
wifi@wifi:/var/www/html/git_training$ git reset
wifi@wifi:/var/www/html/git_training$ git status
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    test.txt

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

At this particular point you can **stash** the files or you can directly change to **development** branch unless you wont get any issues with switching the branch else you must stash the files and then switch, and you will be able to see the **test.txt** file when you do **git status**. Now you can commit as usual.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you just want the changes you committed and pushed to a specific branch to be reflected in another branch as well.

If that is so, just pull the other branch into the current branch as follows:

1. Switch to the branch you want to pull the changes to:

   git checkout
2. Pull the other branch into you local branch:

   git pull

   This will do the following: Fetch the other branch. Merge the other branch into you current branch.

If not, please describe the question further for a better solution. :)